# Raw UDP socket get stuck on recvfrom

Tags: c++, c, sockets

i'm sending dns packet (type A) over raw socket. I get good result from my default DNS server
the problem is that my code get stuck in "recvfrom" , i can see the outgoing request packet and the incoming answer over wireshark (no errors) . I try all kind of manipulation like using different sockets for outgoing and incoming packets, trying "recv" ... but nothing seems to work. I will appreciate any help.

```
int main() {
char hostname[100];

//Get the DNS servers from the resolv.conf file
get_dns_servers();
struct sockaddr_in sin;
// dest
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons (53);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (dns_servers[0]);

//Get the hostname from the terminal
cout << "\nEnter Hostname to Poison : ";
scanf("%s" , hostname);


//Create a raw socket of type IPPROTO
int s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);

if(s == -1)
{
    //socket creation failed, may be because of non-root privileges
    perror("Failed to create raw socket");
    exit(1);
}

dns_packet *pak = new dns_packet("192.168.203.128",(uint16_t) 50115,(in_addr_t) sin.sin_addr.s_addr, (in_port_t) sin.sin_port, (int) 3333, hostname);

//Send the packet
if (sendto (s, pak->datagram, pak->iph->tot_len ,   0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof (sin)) < 0)
{
    perror("sendto failed");
}
//Data send successfully
else
{
    printf ("Packet Send. Length : %d \n" , pak->iph->tot_len);
}

//Receive the answer
int i = sizeof(sin);
unsigned char buf[65536];

cout << "\nReceiving answer..." << endl;
if(recvfrom (s,(char*)buf , sizeof(buf) , 0 , (struct sockaddr*)&sin , (socklen_t*)&i ) < 0)
{
    perror("recvfrom failed");
}

read_answer(buf);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Thanks @2to1mux, i finally succeeded. I read somewhere that i can't bind port to a raw socket (binding is transport layer concept). And i get on wireshark destination port unreachable, so i opened another socket for incoming packets and bind the socket to my incoming packet destination port. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no call to bind in your code. You need to bind to an interface before you can receive anything.

EDIT: Also, I notice you're using a raw socket. When using raw sockets, it's often easier to use recvmsg() instead of recvfrom(). Here is a link for recvmsg(): http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Open_C_Sockets:_recv,_recvfrom,_recvmsg_methods